# How do I get closure compiler configured to run on Google App Engine Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-closure

I suspect I need to add an Ant task somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do that... App Engine has a whitelist for the classes that you are allowed to use, and I assume the Closure Compiler would most probably be useful in your case if you can send its output to files, which won't be allowed.

What you probably want to do is have your own local development environment where you develop using the Google Closure Compiler and then deploy the resulting output to your App Engine cloud service.

Or, if you really intent to call the compiler on the fly on AppEngine, do do some JavaScript meta-programming or something along these lines, then you'll probably facing some fun debugging and tweaking to get it to work. I would assume you could hook yourself onto the compiler to get the intended output in-memory instead of outputting to a file, and then inject it into your served content.

But no Ant file will magically do this for you, and even "run" the closure compiler for you on AppEngine. I think you are a bit confused as to what these technologies are and imply.